# optimizing nested for loop wrt time taken

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, numpy, data-structures

I have a dictionary of dictionaries. Let's say 'data' and a numpy array. Let's say 'stats'.
i am trying to check whether:-

first and second columns of the numpy array exist in a range of 2 keys each in my dictionary of dictionaries OR if those 2 keys exist in range of columns in my numpy array.

Providing my code for reference
The main issue is this is taking a lot of time would really appreciate any help on making this run faster.

Any help will be appreciated, Thank you

```
final = []
for x,y,w,h,area in stats[:]:
    valid = True
    if any([(x in range(s["hpos_start"]-2, s["hpos_end"] + 2) and y in range(s["vpos_start"]-2, s["vpos_end"] + 2)) or ((int(s['hpos_start']) in range(x,x+w) and int(s['vpos_start']) in range(y,y+h))) for _, s in data.items()]):
        valid = False
    if valid:
        final.append([x,y,w,h])
```

sample for stats =

```
         [[    246       1102    1678   2214  172182],
         [     678       1005    1688   2214  3528850],
         [     1031      241     17     23    331]]
```

sample for data =

```
{'0': {
  'hpos_start': 244,
  'hpos_end': 296,
  'vpos_start': 1099,
  'vpos_end': 3898,
  },
 '1': {
  'hpos_start': 679,
  'hpos_end': 952,
  'vpos_start': 231,
  'vpos_end': 281
  },
 '2': {'hpos_start': 1077,
  'hpos_end': 1174,
  'vpos_start': 231,
  'vpos_end': 281
  }}
```

stats is  about size (352,5)
data is about size 212

can be more than above as well

Comment: Could you give a sample of stats and data content so we can run the code ? How big are these data ?

Comment: @Malo added the same.

Comment: after testing the answers, you could tell us how big and how long it takes with your data ?

Comment: @malo replied on your answer, Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to turn both stats and data into numpy arrays and then figuring out a way to achieve your particular filtering *without* the need to use *explicit* `for`-loops. That's the whole advantage of numpy! Also then you'd use special indexing methods to generate your `final` array instead of building it piece by piece. Appending to a list can be somewhat slow...

For a small but easy-to-implement speedup: When you use `any` or `all` in your code, you should avoid passing it a `list` when you can pass it a generator expression instead. If you just remove the square brackets from inside the `any`, you *should* see a little speedup, because you will avoid always building the full intermediate list! The cool thing about `any` (and `all`) is that, when working on iterators, they have what's called short-circuiting: As soon as `any` finds an item that's `True`, it knows it can just stop looking at the rest of the items because the answer will be `true`. Likewise as soon as `all` finds an item that's `False` it will stop looking at the rest and just return `False`.

But really, turn your inputs into numpy arrays (or maybe a numpy array and a pandas dataframe) and then try to figure out a way to avoid for-loops.

Comment: Trying to do the same @Lagerbaer have turned stats and data both into pandas dataframe and trying to use np.where to solve my problem. Will let you know how i end up actually solving it. Thanks a lot for your suggestion , appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

To test and time your code, I run it in a for loop 100000 times. Your code runs in 1.406 seconds. I propose the code below: replace "in range" tests by limit tests, supress int(..) casts, and it runs in 0.609 seconds on my pc. Have a try on your pc and see what speed you can gain :

```
import time
start = time.process_time()

for i in range(100000) :

    ## 100000x 0.609
    final = []
    for x,y,h,w,area in stats:
        if    any([
                    ((
                        (s["hpos_start"]-2) <= x and x <= (s["hpos_end"] + 2)
                    and
                        ((s["vpos_start"]-2)<=y and y <=( s["vpos_end"] + 2))
                    ))
                    or ((
                           (x<= s['hpos_start'] <= (x+w))
                           and
                           (y<= s['vpos_start'] <=(y+h))
                       ))
                    for s in data.values()
              ]):
            pass
        else:
            final.append([x,y,w,h])
    
print(time.process_time() - start)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.This gave me a good boost but i think a vectorized solution will be an ideal solution (as suggested by lagerbaer in answers section) for this problem as your code still takes some time to run when a good amount of data is present.

Just for your reference for stats of size (352,5) data is about size 212
my code took 7.326178312301636 seconds
yours took 0.1902620792388916